# Is a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ semialgebraic if and only if all its orbits are?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-groups, semialgebraic-geometry

A subset $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is called *semialgebraic* if it is of the form
$$
X = \bigcup_{finite} \bigcap_{finite} \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \colon f_{i,j}(x) \star 0 \}
$$
where $\star$ represents any of the symbols $=, \leq , \geq, <, >$ and $f_{i,j} \in \mathbb{R}[X_{11}, \ldots , X_{nn}]$.

A subgroup $G < \operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is called a *semialgebraic group* if $G$ is a semialgebraic subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Is the following true?

**Conjecture:** A subgroup $G < \operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is semialgebraic if and only if for every $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the orbit $G.p \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is semialgebraic.

One direction follows from the Tarski-Seidenberg transfer principle: If $G$ is semialgebraic, orbits
$$
G.p = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \colon \exists g \in G , x=g.p\}
$$
are semialgebraic. What about the other direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counter-example. Consider the subgroup of $GL(2,{\mathbb R})$ consisting of matrices with rational determinants.

Another example is the following subgroup of $SO(4)$: Unitary matrices (elements of $U(2)$) whose complex  determinants are roots of unity.

Conjecture. Suppose that $G<GL(n, {\mathbb R})$ is a subgroup with semialgebraic orbits. Then $G$ contains a semialgebraic subgroup with exactly the same orbits as $G$.

Comment: Why is the orbit of (1,0) under the action of your first group equal to $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: Ah, because of the matrices 
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Strichcoder: Because already $SL(2,R)$ acts transitively on the set of nonzero vectors.

Comment: Do you know of a semialgebraic subgroup of $\{g \in \operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}) \colon \det g \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ with the same orbits?

Comment: @Strichcoder: Of course, $SL(2,R)$.

Comment: Sorry, what is R?

Comment: @Strichcoder ${\mathbb R}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151667/discussion-between-strichcoder-and-moishe-kohan).